# Cant Create tables in access with pyodbc

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I am trying to create tables in a MS Access DB with python using pyodbc but when I run my script no tables are created and no errors are given. My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pyodbc

con = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=Z:\Data\Instruments\testDB.accdb; Provider=MSDASQL;')
cur = con.cursor()
string = "CREATE TABLE TestTable(symbol varchar(15), leverage double, shares integer, price double)"
cur.execute(string)
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to commit the transaction:

```
import pyodbc

con = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=Z:\Data\Instruments\testDB.accdb; Provider=MSDASQL;')
cur = con.cursor()
string = "CREATE TABLE TestTable(symbol varchar(15), leverage double, shares integer, price double)"
cur.execute(string)
con.commit()
```

Comment: Thank you! Half a day debugging why my DB was completely stuck. Create table was never committed and kept entire DB waiting.

Answer (score 3):

Additional solutions that do not require a manual commit are:

Set `autocommit = True` when the connection instance is created.

Eg:

```
con = pyodbc.connect(your_connection_string, autocommit = True)
```

**OR**

Use a `with` statement that, according to [Python Database connection Close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783238/python-database-connection-close), will commit anything before the connection is deleted at the end of the `with` block.

Eg:

```
with pyodbc.connect(your_connection_string) as con:

    CREATE_TABLE_CODE_WITHOUT_COMMIT

UNRELATED_CODE
```