# “'NoneType' object is not iterable” error when trying to read sql query with pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I came across the below post, which is my exact situation. I have a large SQL query which has the below format:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

CREATE TABLE x
INSERT INTO x

CREATE TABLE y
INSERT INTO y
.
.
.

SELECT * FROM x join y
where a

UNION

SELECT * FROM x join y
where b
```

The query works perfectly fine, returning over 15k rows as intended. When I try and read this into a dataframe in python, I get the 'NoneType' object is not iterable error, as described in the below link. I see the original poster converted his query into a stored procedure. I am wondering if there is another way to resolve this error, without writing a stored procedure.

[Python Pandas read_sql_query “'NoneType' object is not iterable” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48287404/python-pandas-read-sql-query-nonetype-object-is-not-iterable-error)

**UPDATE - inserting python code**

```
server = 'server'
query = 'test.sql'
db  ='db'       
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQL Server};Server=' + dbserver + ';Database=' + database + ';Trusted_Connection=yes;')
fd = open(query, 'r')
df = pd.read_sql_query(fd.read(),conn)
fd.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Hi, can you also put your python code?

Comment: `read_sql` is essentially for reading the table/sql and fetching the rows. You can run those create statements separately and keep the select statements with union alone in the query. Another way is of course to create a stored procedure.

Comment: @mad_ I tried what you mentioned. I basically split the create statements into one SQL, and wrote to dataframe using read_sql_query. Then I did the same with the select statement, which i wrote to a separate dataframe using read_sql_query. This resulted in the same error.

Comment: can you post how you are executing those statements?

Comment: `server = 'server'
query = 'test.sql'
db  ='db'       
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQL Server};Server=' + dbserver + ';Database=' + database + ';Trusted_Connection=yes;')
sql_1 = "..."
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql_1,conn)                                                                                sql_2 = "..."                                                                                                                     df_2 = pd.read_sql_query(sql_2,conn)`

Comment: Once had the same problem and figured out on PL/SQL query hitting enter was ok in the editor but when sending it as a query I had to add semicolons. Would you also check if this works?

Comment: `;` will basically separate each query from one another in most of the databases. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html docs shows the read_sql is good for reading the tables in pandas dataframes and not great for sql execution. you have `pyodbc` driver which you can use to run your create statements. Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744742/cant-create-tables-in-access-with-pyodbc. I think you can run series of queries using pyodbc execute statements.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the issue as this was once the problem with my query.
When sending the query, make sure *semicolons* aren't missed. 
On the editor, hitting enter works just fine, but when you're sending it, either as a string or from your files, you'd have to explicitly add it at the end of each statement.