# Mysql connector for Python3

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to make Database class for python3, but not going so well. The current code I have gives me the following error:

```
return self.cursor
[Previous line repeated 995 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076220/python-mysqldb-connection-in-a-class) thread as a reference, but I'm more interested in using Mysql/MariaDB. But I figure that the wrapper itself shouldn't be that much of a difference from SQLite.

This is my code

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            connection = mysql.connector.connect(
                        host='localhost',
                        database='db',
                        user='root',
                        # charset='utf8mb4',
                        passwd='')
            if connection.is_connected():
               db_Info = connection.get_server_info()
               print("Connected to MySQL database... MySQL Server version on ",db_Info)
               cursor = connection.cursor(prepared=True)
               cursor.execute("select database();")
               record = cursor.fetchone()
               print ("Your connected to - ", record[0])
        except Error as e :
            print ("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self):
        if(connection.is_connected()):
            cursor.commit()
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
        else:
            print('Something went wrong...')

    @property
    def cursor(self):
        return self.cursor

    def commit(self):
        self.connection.commit()

    def execute(self, sql, params=None):
        self.cursor.execute(sql, params or ())

    def fetchall(self):
        return self.cursor.fetchall()

    def fetchone(self):
        return self.cursor.fetchone()

    def query(self, sql, params=None):
        self.cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
        return self.fetchall()
```

I have also commented out `charset=utf8mb4` because of the error `LookupError: unknown encoding: utf8mb4`, but thats for another thread...